# Silent Installing of android applications, without the user interaction

Tags: android, android-install-apk, silent-installer

i am trying to install few apk from my application to the device.

my application is a system app,
my device is not rooted

is there any way to install the apk silently, which i want to?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
try{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("install path/file.apk");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
}
catch(e){}
```

Comment: i got this exception, java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [install, /storage/self/primary/PlusMessage.apk] Working Directory: null Environment: null
is there any permissions am i missing ?
thanks for your input anyway